# What is the etymology of the word "dada" as it is used in French to mean "horse" (cheval)?

Tags: étymologie, enfants

(Question in the "Title Header" restated in French):

> Quelle est l’étymologie du mot « dada » tel qu'il est employé en
>   français pour signifier « cheval » (horse) ?

When our children were little “poussins,” Mama Coq and I would bounce them on our feathered laps cackling « A cheval … . / A **dada** sur mon bidet … » .

Although they’re much too big for that now, we still, for old time’s sake, bring out our “Jeu de **dada**/Petits chevaux” game board to play each year when they “fly south for the winter (holidays),” which they will soon do, and which, I suppose, is what inspired my question at this particular time.

I know that “dada” is children-speak / baby talk for “cheval,” which my “Le Robert-Micro” confirms, and the earliest reference that I can find is the following entry from the 5th edition of the Dictionnaire de l'Académie Françoise, Volume 1 (1798-99 [L’an VII de la Republique]):

[DADA](https://books.google.com/books?id=tjhCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=%22DADA.%20s.%20m.%20Terme%20dont%20se%20servent%20les%20enfans%20et%20ceux%20qui%20leur%20parlent,%20et%20qui%20signifie%20un%20cheval.%20Un%20petit%20dada.%20Aller%20%C3%A0%20dada%22&source=bl&ots=vdT8kdHbnH&sig=SnrA4Mnk6TeMr1Paj4BxsiTuy18&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m5uNVJmXMMG1sQSgroCgAg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22DADA.%20s.%20m.%20Terme%20dont%20se%20servent%20les%20enfans%20et%20ceux%20qui%20leur%20parlent%2C%20et%20qui%20signifie%20un%20cheval.%20Un%20petit%20dada.%20Aller%20%C3%A0%20dada%22&f=false):

> s. m. Terme dont se servent les enfan[t]s et ceux qui leur parlent, et
>   qui signifie un cheval. Un petit dada. Aller à dada

However, I need help to discover and understand the origins of the word as used in this sense.

When asked where « dada » came from (and why), Mama Coq responded:

> Well it’s just what we [as French children] called horses and rocking horses because
>   “cheval” was too hard for us to say.  It’s nonsensical baby talk, so I don't
>   see why you are even trying to find any rhyme or reason for it ([you
>   stupid sh#t-head]). Now please get off your butt and take out the garbage, darling.

Be that (the above parenthetical) as it may, I don’t accept that answer, because I fail to see either:

1. any phonetic connection between “dada” and “cheval,” which often exists between the real word and a baby’s failed attempt to say it [brother = bubba in English / Tante = Tata in French, for example] or
2. any "onomatopoetic" connection between “dada” and the vocal sound made by horses (whinny/neigh in English / hennissement in French), which also often exists between the real word (especially an animal) and the “word” used by babies to identify the animal [a cow = a moo-moo in English / un oiseau = un cui-cui in French, for example].

So no, I can’t accept that ANY (much less, ALL) contemporary French babies simply hear the word “cheval” or hear the horse’s “hennissement” and immediately experience a eureka moment in their perhaps small, but not-so-nonsensical brains, to-wit:

> Eureka!! From this day forward I shall call that thing “un dada!”

No, I'm thinking that this must be a term expressly **coined** (apparently pre-1798) and espressly **taught** to French babies (as if they don't already have enough vocabulary and grammar rules to learn!) **by adults**, who were/are either:

1. the ones actually possessing the type of brains that would be required to concoct such a "nonsensical word" (if that's all it is) for "cheval"   **OR**
2. (and this is what I believe [and on the descendants of whom I’m counting to answer my question]) the ones possessing the etymologic knowledge that logically connects “dada” to “cheval.”

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: C'est une expression spécifique à une certain région?

Comment: Ma femme est de Picardie donc PEUT-ETRE le mot reste là, mais je crois que c’est partout en France, aumoins pour comprendre "dada" pour "cheval" dans les variations régionales/familiales de la chanson "A cheval/dada sur mon bidet" et aussi dans le "Jeu de dada" avec ses pièces de jeu en forme de cheval/tête de cheval. Ici (US) "Dada" est court pour "Daddy" qui="Père," qui augmentait la confusion de nos enfants qui chantaient 'A Dada …." quand ils étaient sur mes genoux, puis "A maman…" sur ses genoux et même parfois "A Mémé…" sur les genoux de leurs grand-mères! Et chez vous @Vincent ?

Comment: Au Québec on entends parfois: Ça c'est mon dada = C'est quelque chose que j'aime beaucoup. Ou encore pour parler du dadaïsme, un courant artistique populaire du siècle passé.

Comment: Je n'avais également jamais entendu « dada » pour parler d'un cheval. À moins que la tendance change, ce n'est pas vraiment utilisé au Québec.

Comment: AFAIK, ce n'est plus vraiment utilisé.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Dada* a une origine onomatopéique, le bruit que font sur les pavés les sabots des chevaux au pas: *da, da, da, da*, ou plus vraisemblablement au trot: *dada, dada, dada, dada*. Le plus récent *tagada, tagada, tagada* correspond lui sans équivoque au galop.

Le dictionnaire historique de la langue française (sld Alain Rey) indique pour *dada* : « Formation onomatopéique du langage enfantin désignant le cheval (1508) »

Comment: Voici la référence donnée par le {Le dictionnaire historique de la  langue française (sld Alain Rey): « Formation onomatopéique du langage enfantin désignant le cheval (1508). »

Comment: Merci Laure ! Je met à jour ma réponse.

Answer (score 5):

Mama Coq  a lu le *[Le Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/dada)* qui lui attribue une étymologie enfantine, … elle est pleine de bon sens.

Le petit Robert fait remonter l'origine écrite à 1508, "peut-être" de *dia*.

Mais la répétition du même phonème comme dans papa, mama[n], bonbon, pipi, caca … plaide pour une origine enfantine.

Les très jeunes enfants inventent des mots bien à eux, et parfois les adultes les reprennent à leur compte, ou s'en servent pour mieux communiquer avec eux, celui-là est tellement pratique que tout le monde s'en est servi.

Semble-t-il depuis fort longtemps les enfants enfourchent un bâton en criant *da, da*, interjection que les paysans lançaient encore dans les années 60 pour faire avancer et encourager les chevaux en secouant les rênes sur leurs dos, après leur avoir crié *huuue* pour lancer l'attelage et ensuite *hoooo, hoooo* pour l'arrêter en tirant sur ces mêmes rênes et enfin *aaarrré* (avec un *r* roulé) s'il fallait le faire reculer.

Je n'ai pas d'autre explication tirée par les cheveux ou inventée à posteriori pour faire correspondre *cheval* et *dada*.

Les adultes du *[mouvement dada](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dada)* ont 'enfourché' cette monture pour rajeunir les façons de penser.

Comment: "hue" est plus répandu que ... "da"?

Comment: @ChrisW *Hue* était lancé pour mettre les chevaux en branle, mais ce n'est pas un mot que vous pouvez crier souvent pour indiquer au chevaux qu'il faut continuer à faire un effort : essayez de le répéter en tenant les mancherons de la charrue tout en essayant de sillonner droit ! Le *a* de *da* ressemble alors au *han* du bûcheron.

Comment: Ce *da ! da !* est souvent remplacé par la variante *ya ! ya !* aujourd'hui dans certaines régions. Mais c'est très vraisemblablement de la même origine. Excellente réponse à une excellente question.