# L'onomatopée « ti-galop » du cheval pour enfant ?

Tags: orthographe, québec, zoologie, onomatopées

Je connais une expression/onomatopée qu'on emploie au Québec (à tout le moins) quand on « fait le cheval pour un enfant » qu'on a sur ses genoux : « ti-galop » (on répète à chaque mouvement). On trouve ça par exemple dans une chanson de [Paul Piché](https://youtu.be/YMgpS3owBZQ) ou dans un extrait d'entrevue avec [Jean-Claude Lauzon](https://youtu.be/t4wKQ-Ojyyo) (contexte de la référence à [Plamondon](https://youtu.be/Tlqq4ByU1kg)) qui emploie ce qui semble être une variante (ça ressemble à « ti-gedup »). Il s'agit de trois syllabes et étrangement ça correspond dans mon esprit au son que font les sabots quand le cheval est *au galop* (même si je cheval a quatres pates il semble que les pattes avant produisent un son qui se combine).

- A-t-on ça en français métropolitain ou ailleurs dans la francophonie
  et autrement qu'emploie-t-on dans ce contexte ?
- A-t-on un autre exemple d'un substantif désignant une action
  animalière qu'on emploie comme onomatopée pour reproduire le son
  qu'elle fait ; est-ce courant ?
- Pour une personne qui est familière avec l'onomatopée, emploie-t-on «
  ti-galop » ou « ti-gedup » et dans le deuxième cas comment écrit-on
  ça (est-ce vraiment « ti-gedup ») ; laquelle est la plus fréquente ;
  la deuxième est-elle une déformation de la première ; pourquoi il y en a deux ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Je ne connaissais pas ***ti-galop*** ou ***ti-gedup*** mais ça pourrait être utilisé ici sans surprendre personne. La version habituelle est ***tagada***.

   Voir : [What is the etymology of the word "dada" as it is used in French to mean "horse" (cheval)?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-word-dada-as-it-is-used-in-french-to-mean-horse))

Answer (score 2):

En français métropolitain cette onomatopée est « tagada ».

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tagada))
> **Étymologie**
>
> (XXe siècle) Probablement dérivé de l’onomatopée *tac*, auparavant, le bruit de galop était représenté par *patati patata* ; (1650) *patatin patatac*.
>
> tagada \ta.ɡa.da\ masculin
>
> Onomatopée enfantine rappelant le bruit de galop d’un cheval.

On emploie une onomatopée très similaire morphologiquement pour le bruit que font les wagons en déplacement sur les rails. ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Allons_y_gaiement/lUCaDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22tagadac%22&pg=PT41&printsec=frontcover))

[image]

On l'emploie aussi pour les chevaux, en répétitions, comme le montre cette [référence-ci](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Petite_Suzanne/uBmNDgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22tagadac%22&pg=PT278&printsec=frontcover).

[image]

La variante suivante combine les deux formes. ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/THEATRE_COMPLET_T_2/3rQx2EHvT1kC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22tagadac%22&pg=PA165&printsec=frontcover))

[image]

Les variantes envisagées ne semblent pas être utilisées. On peut même se demander, vu la prononciation « effilée » de Lauzon, s'il ne s'agirait pas tout simplement de « ti-galop » dans lequel a et o tendent vers e.